Service Bus SendMessageAsync failing when ApplicationProperties is set with values from a Json Deserialized Dictionary<string,object>
I have a scenario I need to set ApplicationProperties to a Azure Service Bus message. I have dictionary of key, value type <string,object>. I also use System.Text.Json for deserializing the payload from request.
I tried to recreate issue. I have a method which gives me the body payload. here I named it GetParams. It gives a nullable Dictionary of <string,object>
 IDictionary<string, object>? GetParams()
{
    bool shouldReturnParameters = true;
    if (shouldReturnParameters)
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"Parameter1\": 123, \"Parameter2\": \"Some value\"}";
        var parameters = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

        return parameters;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
} 

Now in main method I try to send the message
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    var message = new ServiceBusMessage(data);
    IDictionary<string, object>? params = GetParams();
    if (params != null)
    {
        foreach (var param in params)
        {
            message.ApplicationProperties[param.Key] = param.Value;
        }
    }

    await sender.SendMessageAsync(message); //ERROR!

Now I get unhandled exception  System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Serialization failed due to an unsupported type, System.Text.Json.JsonElement.
When I debug the code param.Value had a property called ValueKind apart from the value. When I just hardode the values when assigning values like ApplicationProperties["Parameter1"] = 123 then it worked.
So is there a general solution for this problem. Do I have to do .toString() and do if checks to check each type like string, number, boolean etc and then parse the value to that type.

ApplicationProperties is of Dictionary<string, object> type. Individual values can only be made up of simple types Azure Service Bus allows as documentated.

string
bool
byte
sbyte
short
short
int
unit
long
long
float
decimal
double
char
Guid
DateTime
DateTimeOffset
Stream
Uri
TimeSpan

If you need to assign an unsupported type, you'll need to serialize and store it as a string

Thanks. I was actually aware of this and send only values that belong within these types. My issue is when I use system.text.json on frontend request it gives the key string but value is In JsonElement instead of object
